# Why is onTokenRefresh not firing?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to firebase messaging and flutter. According to the flutter [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) package [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onTokenRefresh.html), `onTokenRefresh` is fired when a new FCM token is generated. And according to Google's firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#java_2) there are two scenarios that triggers token generation:

> 1. When a new token is generated on initial app startup
> 2. Whenever an existing token is changed

Here is a simplified version of the `main` function of my application. After each execution, I delete the app from the emulator and the displayed token does indeed change. Despite this, `onTokenRefresh` is never fired and it should if my understanding of the documentation is correct.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((String token) {
    print("New token: $token");
  });

  String token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  print("Token: $token");
  //runApp(MyApp());
}
```

As I said, I'm new to flutter, dart and firebase messaging, is there something I'm fundamentally misunderstanding? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I figured it out. I noticed that sometimes, the `onTokenRefresh` does indeed fire. And I was wondering if it had something to do with how the flutter application is launched onto the emulator, in the sense that there is a race condition between when the token is generated and the listener attached.

To get the app to appear to start for the first time, I wiped the app data. Unfortunately this causes the flutter to automatically disconnect from the app which means I won't see the output of the print statement. So instead of trying to print when the token generation occurs, I assigned a value from the `onTokenRefresh` listener to a variable. I then updated a text widget with the value of the variable. And `onTokenRefresh` does indeed fire each time at start up if the app data has previously been wiped.

Comment: When you had wiped the app data and opened the app again, the `print` statement in the `onTokenRefresh` should have worked, hasn't it? Why did you need to assign a value somewhere, also wiping the data would have also cleared the variable data. I am not sure how this is an answer.